# Poetry add pkg got "HTTPResponse.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'"

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I create a new env with python 3.10.9 using conda. I have poetry installed using pip, after I add several packages, the `poetry add pkg` command didn't work with error message:

```
HTTPResponse.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5rbH.png)

I googled about the problem and no answers to it, how to solve it?

have the poetry add command working

Answer (score 5):

downgrade urllib3 package (<2.0)

Answer (score 3):

There is an error with poetry's **dependency on liburl3**.

First, you can try **updating poetry**:

```
pip install --upgrade poetry
```

Try running poetry again and check if the error still appears.

If yes, the dependency error can be resolved by **downgrading the urllib3 package**:

```
pip install "urllib3>=1.26.16,<2.0.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

use pip downgrade urllib3 package to 1.26.15

to avoid automatically upgrading urllib3 when running the poetry command, it is better to fix urllib3 version like this：

```
poetry add urllib3==1.26.15
```